# In-App Purchases "waiting for review" for a lot of time

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Hello I added 5 days ago my first In-App purchase to iTunes connect and connected it to my update.
Now apple even started reviewing the In-App Purchase?
How long does it normally take until they start reviewing it?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not the place to ask this question! Read http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: Oh.... Sorry haven't noticed it...

Comment: Don't exactly know why this is off-topic because iTunes Connect is a resource used by many developers/programmers, and **fits the scope of Stack Overflow.**

iTunes Connect is, quoting the scope, **a "software tool commonly used by programmers."** If you want to make an app for iOS, you _have_ to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

around 5 business days, but up to a few weeks. Patience is a virtue! (with apple especially)